# How to detect specific number of length before and after decimal point in vuetify form number input

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

At the input, I want to accept decimal and floating number only. Max 5 digits are allowed before decimal point and max 2 digits are allowed after decimal point. Initially, I have defined my rules like this way:

```
priceRules: [
      v => !!v || 'Price is required',
      v => /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(v) || 'Number only',
      v => (v && v.toString().split('.')[0].length <= 5) || 'No more than 5 digits before the decimal point'
    ]
```

I want to add another rule which show error message if user type more than 2 digits after decimal point. After adding the last rule, it's not working.

```
priceRules: [
          v => !!v || 'Price is required',
          v => /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(v) || 'Number only',
          v => (v && v.toString().split('.')[0].length <= 5) || 'No more than 5 digits before the decimal point',
          v => (v && v.toString().split('.')[1].length > 2) || 'No more than 2 digits after the decimal point'. // this is not working
    ]
```

How to make it is working?

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/abyWPMv?editors=101)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
priceRules: [
  v => !!v || 'Price is required',
  v => /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(v) || 'Number only',
  v => (v && v.toString().split('.')[0].length <= 5) || 'No more than 5 digits before the decimal point',
  v => (v && v.toString().split('.').length < 2) || (v && v.toString().split('.')[1].length <= 2) || 'No more than 2 digits after the decimal point'
]
```

this checks if `split` result has more than one element first and then checks for the max digits after `.`